# The semaphore period has expired on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I maintain some software that makes a tcp socket connection to a different piece of software and sends data back and forth (pretty basic stuff there).  We use boost asio to handle reading and writing of data over the socket connection.  We have a client that has deployed this software on Windows7.  The client has been having issues with our software not being able to maintain a reliable socket connection.  One thing I have noticed is that quite often the networking callback are receiving the error: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

This error is not coming from anywhere in our code (or the boost code).  I've done some research on it and I found a Microsoft Knowledge base article on this error for Windows XP (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325487).  I've seen a few people ask questions about this error on Windows7, but they're all in regards to moving files to different drives, nothing regarding network connections.

What does this error mean in regards to Windows7?  Does the knowledge base article I mentioned still apply to Windows7?

Comment: Also, please let me know if I've posted this to the wrong forum.  The question feels like its in a grey area between StackOverflow, ServerFault, and SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the semaphore timeout problem with USB3.0 device drivers. I found reinstalling the device drivers solved the problem. The problem seems to be corrupted drivers from what I've learnt, and it creeps back in when more software or different USB hardware is connected, from my experience.

in your case, ask your client to reinstall the appropriate network drivers and/or check if they have any network hardware connected via USB3.0, in which case, they should reinstall those drivers.